How to show URL-decoded URL in the Network pane of F12 DevTool?
Here is the screenshot of the Network pane in my F12 DevTool.

I'd like to see the Name or Path in the Network pane in a URL-decoded format. Is that possible?
I try to find out stuff related to this but nothing found. I expected a way to "see" the Path or Name in URL-decoded format.
